# Jquery UI Sortable, Scrolling (jsFiddle Example)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, overflow, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to figure out how to get my 'sortable lists' to scroll while I am dragging a list element.

The scroll works fine in the list I am dragging *from* but not in the list I am dragging *to*.

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/pacbC/1/

***Another question asking a similar thing:***

[jQuery sortable container scroll div with overflow auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857065/jquery-sortable-container-scroll-div-with-overflow-auto)

PS. Pivotaltracker, [www.pivotaltracker.com](http://www.pivotaltracker.com) does this well.

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but I struggled with this for a few hours today so I figured I'd share what I learned.

Sortable scrolling is a function of the scrollParent's offset, its current scroll position, the current item position, and the scrollSensitivity.  The sortable executes _mouseStart when you start dragging.  This sets the scrollParent and caches its offset for the current sort.  Armed with this knowledge, we can do a small shuffle in the over event handler:

```
over: function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.data('sortableItem').scrollParent = ui.placeholder.parent();
    ui.item.data('sortableItem').overflowOffset = ui.placeholder.parent().offset();
}
```

Over fires when the dragged element changes containers.  The placeholder has already moved to the new container when you hit the over event.  The code gets the new scrollParent and recaches the offset.

I forked Tats_innit's fiddle for brevity's sake: http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/84/

The scrollParent gets referenced in other places throughout the event structure so I'm not sure this is bulletproof.  Still, I think this is a good starting point.  If I encounter any gotchas, I'll update this answer.

Comment: I love you. This is an extremely clean solution to a potentially very tricky problem. I haven't encountered any gotchas with this yet and it works right out of the box for me! Will update if I find anything odd.

Comment: beautiful solution--saved me hours of work, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/1/

Please let me know if I missed anything, and slo see my previous reply around this: [Automatically scroll droppable div whilst dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986159/automatically-scroll-droppable-div-whilst-dragging/10986522#10986522)

*Behaviour* : Now the div where you are dragging to will also scroll. (rest code is below)

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$(function() {
    var sortlists = $("#List1, #List2").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        connectWith: '#List1, #List2',
        helper: 'original',
        scroll: true
    }).on('scroll', function() {
        sortlists.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });
});​
```

Comment: Place item 1 and 3 in second scroll box. Then, set both scrollbars up high. Now you can not drag item 2 from first scroll box and drop it between 8/9 in second scroll box because the scrollbars are different in height. Maybe solution is to temporary set height in scroll box1 to be more than length of scroll box 2.

Comment: Hiya @arttronics howz it going? :) yep because the `on` even gets bind to the `this` object i.e. the div from where the user drags when the list become unequal hieght **solution** can be: Drag it to the div and then scroll it to bottm or possibly playing around with `this` object and always choosing the bigger conatiner as a scroll referece, cheers for the comment though.

Comment: It's too bad it's a non-working demo as reported in the other [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986159/automatically-scroll-droppable-div-whilst-dragging/10986522#10986522) you provided by many users yesterday. **-1** for not useful answer.

Comment: Okies this is funny I got downvoted in my previous question for nothing, please dont do that. Its a viable solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986159/automatically-scroll-droppable-div-whilst-dragging/10986522#10986522

Comment: No it is not, please test yourself when scrollbars are different length.

Comment: My idea for you in first message I wrote is for this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWwJt/).

Comment: @Tats_innit this does not solve the problem. I am still unable to scroll to the bottom of the connected list with an element from the started list. Binding a `scrollTop()` call to the `this` element on the hover might center the receiving list slightly, but doesn't allow for further dragging!

Comment: @jordan.baucke cool bruv, :P okies:it seems to be behaving fine in my OSX Safari, *or I might have missed something please correct me * . So when I drag the item from list 1 to list 2 then the second list does allow me to drag it to the scroller and put it into the end of the lis. Please let me know if this is wrong behaviour. cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit I just tried it in all browsers in Windows, it doesn't work, see screen capture http://screencast.com/t/cCqm8i4h

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `overflow: auto;` to the parent element, be it `ul` or `#element`, or what have you.